# Display User Name To Right On My 'Mat-toolbar'

Tags: html, angular

I have an `Angular 5` project and on the toolbar I have the following details:

- Sub-menu button
- Company logo
- Company name

These three are fine but now I am being asked to display the following details to the right of the main menu

- Person icon
- Logged in username

Below is the following code in the `app.component.html` file

```
    <mat-sidenav-container>
    <mat-sidenav #sidenav mode="over" opened="false">
        <div class="closeButton">
            <mat-icon (click)="sidenav.toggle()" title="Click to close sub-menu.">clear</mat-icon>
        </div>
        <a>Sidenav content</a>
        <a>This is a really long nameeeeee</a>
        <a>Sidenav content</a>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-toolbar>
        <mat-icon class="subMenuIcon" (click)="sidenav.toggle()" title="Click to open sub-menu.">reorder</mat-icon>
        <img src="./assets/images/Crest.jpg">AJ Bell Information Interface
        <span flex></span>
        <div style="font-size: 15px">
            <mat-icon style="font-size: 25px">person</mat-icon> 
            USERNAME
        </div>
    </mat-toolbar>
</mat-sidenav-container>
<router-outlet>
        <div>this</div>
        <div>is</div>
        <div>the</div>
        <div>main</div>
        <div>body</div>
</router-outlet>
```

As you can see I have tried using `<span flex></span>` and also `float: right` etc but with no joy at all.

I know it will be simple but I'm having coding tunnel and cant think of a solution

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the answer is in the framework documentation, under the examples section : https://material.angular.io/components/toolbar/examples

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `flex: 1 1 auto;`

Have a look at this [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ub4zqr)